# Instances where women wore tefillin

Tags: history, women, tefilin

Up to (and including) the period of the Rishonim, are there multiple documented instances of Jewish women wearing tefillin?

Edit: As discovered by another user on this website, there is another question similar in nature to the question above.  In contrast to the other post, I would like a comprehensive answer with multiple sources and within a more specific time range.

Comment: Why are you inquiring about this? Adding motivation to your question can improve it.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27823/1713

Comment: Would like to add regarding this question, if a woman did put tefillin, would she also put it on during Shabbat?

Comment: It's a good question.  The answer that avoids the question, is that many poskim hold that men can wear tefillin provided that they do not have the intention of fulfilling a mitzvah.  If I recall correctly, the Shulchan Aruch says that people would conceivably wear tefillin on Shabbat because the tefillin acted as a protective amulet in some sense. (There are source(s), I believe the Zohar in particular, that says that one is "chayav mitah" for wearing tefillin.) In short, I believe the question merits a separate post.

Comment: @Zeev http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41169/759

Answer (score 7):

See [this article](http://www.torahmusings.com/2014/02/women-tefillin-and-the-halakhic-process/) for a more comprehensive discussion. Here are some sourced examples of women who donned tefillin:

1. The gemara in [Eruvin Daf 96](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=96&format=pdf) states that Queen Michal (wife of King David) wore tefillin.
2. "[There] is the opinion [that women are obligated to wear tefillin] attributed to two prominent tannaim, R. Meir and R. Yehuda, as cited in multiple Talmudic passages (see, for example, [Kiddushin 35a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=35&format=pdf) and [Eruvin 96a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=96&format=pdf)-[b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=96b&format=pdf))." Presumably their families and students followed the psak.
3. "Rabbi Avigdor Ha-Tzarfati (13<sup>th</sup> century Vienna), [noted] that a few pious women in his time period donned *tefillin*."

Comment: Rashis daughters? No mention

Comment: There is no clear written/historical evidence for it that I am aware of.

Comment: So it is implied but uncertain that [Beruriah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruriah), Rabbi Meir's wife wore tefillin?